# Truncating text in donut chart android

Tags: java, android, path, paint

I have created a donut chart based on custom requirement. But problem is text in bottom and side text are getting truncated which is not fitting correct. Let me know how to fix it?

Here is code.

```
    public class Chart_daily extends View {


private static final String TAG = Chart_daily.class.getName();
    private static final String TEXT_SELLIN = "SELL IN";
    private static final String TEXT_SELLOUT = "SELL OUT";
    private static final String TEXT_GROWTH = "GROWTH";
    Paint paint;
    Paint shadowPaint;
    Path myPath;
    Path shadowPath;
    RectF outterCircle;
    RectF innerCircle;
    RectF shadowRectF;
    RectF textOuterCircle;
    RectF textInnerCircle;
    String numerator;
    String denominator;
    PerformanceData performanceData;
    private float radius;



       public Chart_daily(Context context, ResponseBody responseBody) {
            super(context);
            this.radius = 
 //the value of the donut_height is 132.5dp
(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.donut_height)) / 2;
            this.numerator = "";
            this.performanceData = responseBody.getPerformanceData();
            if (null != performanceData.getTotRetailerCnt()) {
                if (performanceData.getTotRetailerCnt().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    this.denominator = " /";
                } else {
                    this.denominator = " /" + performanceData.getTotRetailerCnt();
                }

            } else {
                this.denominator = " /";
            }

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(radius / 14.0f);

            shadowPaint = new Paint();
            shadowPaint.setColor(0xf0000000);
            shadowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            shadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            shadowPaint.setStrokeWidth(6.0f);
            shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(4, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.SOLID));
            myPath = new Path();
            shadowPath = new Path();
            outterCircle = new RectF();
            innerCircle = new RectF();
            shadowRectF = new RectF();
            textInnerCircle = new RectF();
            textOuterCircle = new RectF();
    //        radius=300;
            float adjust = (.019f * radius);
            //********************************************************************************************

            adjust = .175f * radius;//0.038
            outterCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius * 2 - adjust, radius * 2 - adjust);


            adjust = .375f * radius;//0.276
            innerCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius * 2 - adjust, radius * 2 - adjust);
            //************************************************************************************************


            adjust = .32f * radius;//0.038
            textInnerCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius * 2 - adjust, radius * 2 - adjust);

            adjust = .125f * radius;//0.038
            textOuterCircle.set(adjust, adjust, radius * 2 - adjust, radius * 2 - adjust);


        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            float adjust = (.0095f * radius);

            try {
                String SellinColor = "";
                String SellOutColor = "";
                String GrowthColor = "";
                String SellInCount = "";
                String SellOutCount = "";
                String tdyGrowth = "";
                if (performanceData.getTdySellInColor() != null)
                    SellinColor = "" + performanceData.getTdySellInColor().toString();
                if (performanceData.getTdySellOutColor() != null)
                    SellOutColor = "" + performanceData.getTdySellOutColor().toString();
                if (performanceData.getTdyGrowthColor() != null)
                    GrowthColor = "" + performanceData.getTdyGrowthColor().toString();
                if (performanceData.getTdySellInCount() != null)
                    SellInCount = "" + performanceData.getTdySellInCount();
                if (performanceData.getTdySellOutCount() != null)
                    SellOutCount = "" + performanceData.getTdySellOutCount();
                if (performanceData.getTdyGrowth() != null)
                    tdyGrowth = "" + performanceData.getTdyGrowth();

                if (SellinColor.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                else if (SellinColor.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                else if (SellinColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                else
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkGray));
                drawDonut(canvas, paint, 30, 120, TEXT_SELLIN, SellInCount);

                if (SellOutColor.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                else if (SellOutColor.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                else if (SellOutColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                else
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkGray));
                drawDonut(canvas, paint, 150, 120, TEXT_SELLOUT, SellOutCount);

                if (GrowthColor.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                else if (GrowthColor.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                else if (GrowthColor.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                else
                    paint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorDarkGray));
                drawDonut(canvas, paint, 270, 120, TEXT_GROWTH, tdyGrowth);
                if (performanceData.getTdySmileyColor() != null) {
                    setSmiley(canvas, performanceData.getTdySmileyColor());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void drawDonut(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float start, float sweep, String text, String numerator) {

            if (numerator.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                numerator = "";
            }
            Paint mPaintText_inner;
            float textAdjustment_outer = 50;
            float textAdjustment_inner = 40;
            mPaintText_inner = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaintText_inner.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            mPaintText_inner.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            mPaintText_inner.setTextSize(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textsize_inner));

            Paint mPaintText_outer;
            mPaintText_outer = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaintText_outer.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

            mPaintText_outer.setTextSize(getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textsize_outer));
            mPaintText_outer.setStrokeWidth(1);

            //Draw the ciecle
            myPath.reset();
            myPath.arcTo(outterCircle, start, sweep, false);
            myPath.arcTo(innerCircle, start + sweep, -sweep, false);
            myPath.close();
            canvas.drawPath(myPath, paint);

            if (text == TEXT_GROWTH) {
                Path myTextPath_inner = new Path();
                myTextPath_inner.arcTo(textInnerCircle, start + textAdjustment_inner, sweep, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, myTextPath_inner, 0, 0, mPaintText_inner);
            } else if (text == TEXT_SELLOUT) {
                Path myTextPath_inner = new Path();
                myTextPath_inner.arcTo(textInnerCircle, start + textAdjustment_inner, sweep, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, myTextPath_inner, 0, 0, mPaintText_inner);
            } else {
                Path myTextPath_inner = new Path();
                myTextPath_inner.arcTo(textInnerCircle, start + textAdjustment_inner + 40, -48, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, myTextPath_inner, 16, 14, mPaintText_inner);

            }


            if (text == TEXT_GROWTH) {
                //Draw the numerator of outer text circle
                float padding = textAdjustment_outer;
                //adjust the numerator dynamically as per size
                padding = padding - 6 * (numerator.length() - 1);
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.RED);
                Path myTextPath_outer = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer.arcTo(textOuterCircle, start + padding, 25, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(numerator, myTextPath_outer, -1, 0, mPaintText_outer);

                //Draw the denominator of outer text circle
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                Path myTextPath_outer2 = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer2.arcTo(textOuterCircle, start + textAdjustment_outer + 5, 60, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(denominator, myTextPath_outer2, 0, 0, mPaintText_outer);

            } else if (text == TEXT_SELLOUT) {
                //Draw the numerator of outer text circle
                float padding = textAdjustment_outer;
                //adjust the numerator dynamically as per size
                padding = padding - 6 * (numerator.length() - 1);
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.RED);
                Path myTextPath_outer = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer.arcTo(textOuterCircle, start + padding, 35, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(numerator, myTextPath_outer, -4, 0, mPaintText_outer);

                //Draw the denominator of outer text circle
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                Path myTextPath_outer2 = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer2.arcTo(textOuterCircle, start + textAdjustment_outer + 5, 60, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(denominator, myTextPath_outer2, 0, 0, mPaintText_outer);
            } else {
                //Draw the numerator of outer text circle
                float padding = textAdjustment_outer;
                RectF textOuterCircleSellin;
                textOuterCircleSellin = new RectF();
                float adjustSellin = (.019f * radius);
                adjustSellin = .11f * radius;//0.038
                textOuterCircleSellin.set(adjustSellin, adjustSellin, radius * 2 - adjustSellin, radius * 2 - adjustSellin);

                //adjust the numerator dynamically as per size

                padding = padding + 20 + 7 *(numerator.length() - 1);
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.RED);
                Path myTextPath_outer = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer.arcTo(textOuterCircleSellin, start + padding, -50, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(numerator, myTextPath_outer, 10, 15, mPaintText_outer);

                //Draw the denominator of outer text circle
                mPaintText_outer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                Path myTextPath_outer2 = new Path();
                myTextPath_outer2.arcTo(textOuterCircleSellin, start + textAdjustment_outer + 16, -50, false);
                canvas.drawTextOnPath(denominator, myTextPath_outer2, 10, 15, mPaintText_outer);
            }
        }

        private void setSmiley(Canvas canvas, String smileyType) {
            Resources res = getResources();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            if (smileyType.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_red_profile);
            } else if (smileyType.equalsIgnoreCase("G")) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_green_profile);
            } else {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.smile);
            }

            float adjust_bitmap = .55f * radius;//0.038
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(adjust_bitmap, adjust_bitmap, radius * 2 - adjust_bitmap, radius * 2 - adjust_bitmap), paint);
        }

        public void setGradient(int sColor, int eColor) {
            paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(radius, radius, radius - 5,
                    new int[]{sColor, eColor},
                    new float[]{.6f, .95f}, TileMode.CLAMP));
        }
    }
```

But when i used this in xml and java,

```
//responseBody is nothing but values which I am passing 
 Chart_daily donutChart_daily = new Chart_daily(getBaseContext(), responseBody);
            layout_donutChart_daily.addView(donutChart_daily);
```

But problem is, it's getting hidding, if you see the bottom and left side text.

[image]

Comment: the problem might be the size of the view(canvas)

Comment: Use the margins or padding for ex: mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 50, 20, 20});

Comment: Let me know exactly where I need to use margins?